# Cirq QAOA Tasks returns "iteration over a 0-d array" error

Tags: programming, cirq, qaoa

I'm trying to understand how to use Recirq for QAOA, and I tried to run the notebook for tasks: https://quantumai.google/cirq/experiments/qaoa/tasks. But it gives a "iteration over a 0-d array" error when I run

```
for task in precompute_tasks:              
    precompute_angles(task)
```

I don't know how to fix this. I want to get their code to run for 5 qubits and get an understanding of how to use and maybe modify it.

Comment: Is this the whole code you are using or is there more?

Comment: It comes from the notebook on the website, which can be downloaded or run on Google's colab. It's the 9th cell of the notebook, so I just gave the specific cell that had the problem.

Comment: I see, you pressed the litle play button and got the error right?

Comment: I have downloaded the notebook and run that, as well as running it in colab and pressing the play buttons to run the cells.

Comment: I rebuild your tasks and got the same error. Let me some time to investigate a bit.

Comment: Couldn't solve it. Same error here. Tried to rename and double check everything. Nothing helped...

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug in the notebook / ReCirq - I filed https://github.com/quantumlib/ReCirq/issues/191.

This is a JSON serialization issue when ReCirq is trying to save the task in JSON format.